# iPhone app programming

Tags: iphone, camera, cross-platform

I've built a few iPhone web apps using HTML, CSS, JavaScript, jQuery, PHP, and SQL Queries.  However, I haven't found a way to access the camera with a web app.  If you know of a way to do that, please tell me what to use and how to use it.  If there is no way to access the camera with a web app, I realize I'll have to make a regular app.  What languages should I start to learn? Instagram is a website, so I'm not entirely sure how they did what they did.

So my question is, if I wanted to built an app similar to instagram (where I could access the camera), where should I begin? 
What languages should I learn?

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Instagram is a hybrid. It's an Objective-C iOS application mixed in with a web view.

Answer (score 3):

[PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) might be the right tool for you.

> PhoneGap is an HTML5 app platform that allows you to author native
>   applications with web technologies and get access to APIs and app
>   stores.

See [this reference](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494789/iPhone%3a%20Camera%20API) on its camera API.

Comment: I copied the code of the site, put it online, then got on my phone to test it, and nothing happens when I click the buttons.

Comment: You need to run that code within the PhoneGap framework, not in your regular browser. Check the PhoneGap site for more.

Comment: How do I include the PhoneGap framework in my script? I've looked all over their site for how to do that (I looked at PhoneGap earlier and had this problem).

Comment: You're going to need to do a little learning for this.  PhoneGap is very useful, but I'd suggest reading a little about its functionality and how to develop with it.

Comment: I've looked it up. The only way I've seen how to use it is to open up Xcode and choose to use phonegap. But I don't want to put this on the app store, I want this to be a web app.

Comment: You can not use the camera within a pure web-app.

Comment: Okay, that was my main question really... Darn. I guess I should learn to use objective C

Comment: Not sure why you ignore PhoneGap then. Objective C also will not run within a web browser.